# How to have openned four bitmaps with mores size than 1024x1024?

Tags: android, bitmap

i need to open four bitmaps with higher size than 1024x1024, at the same moment.

Now i only can open four bitmaps if the size doesn't exceed of 1024 in one of the sides.

How can i solve this?

It's a must for mi app.

Comment: You are probably running out of memory as just a guess since you did not paste any code or logs (hint)

Comment: What possible use could this have? I doubt there will be enough spare memory in most devices to facilitate this. Let alone screen size available.

Comment: What are you doing with the bitmaps?

Comment: Very bad, unclear question. After 250 questions you should know better how to ask here. Anyway, I guess this is the memory issue again. Did you read the answers and the duplicate of your [older question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9484114/how-to-work-with-a-lot-of-bitmaps-and-avoid-the-error-bitmap-size-exceeds-vm-b)? This answers it pretty well. Otherwise please elaborate a bit what the problem here is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the solution is to reduce the size of the bitmaps and to recycle all the bitmaps used in the activity.

Answer (score 0):

Try to increase the size of Max VM application heap size in the Virtual device settings from 24 to 32.

Comment: virtual device setings? i'm not using virtual devices, im using real devices for test and debug my apps